# Is it possible to log errors from different apache modules to separate log files?

Tags: apache, logging, apache2.4

Is it possible to separate apache errors from different apache modules to different log files? For example rewrite module would log all errors from rewrite module to rewrite_error_log and all authz errors would log into authz_error_log and everything else would go to general error_log.

**My particular use case:**

I made a virtualhost configuration that has an unreachable path unless you come from certain ip (VPN gateway):

```
<Directory /var/www/my/app/path>
  # Allow Company gateway
  Require ip 1.2.3.4
</Directory>

# Logfiles
ErrorLog  /var/www/logs/app_error.log
CustomLog /var/www/logs/app_access.log combined
```

and it works as intended. Now consider that people hop out of the company VPN and their page requests are denied as intended. Authz_core will error log all these denied page requests with error messages like this:

```
[authz_core:error] [pid 12345] [client 111.222.1.2:12345] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/my/app/path, referer: https://domainname.tld/
```

These messages will clog up the error_log and I would like to redirect all those 'not-important' error logs to a dedicated authz_error_log file. The ratio of authz errors to other errors is thousands to one.

**What I've considered**

- I can turn off those particular authz errors with Loglevel authz:crit but I'd rather have them in a different log file if possible.
- CustomLog can be used with SetEnvIf but I don't know how to set it up to catch modules
- Using Piped Logs to somehow do the separation logic based on grepping the error message for module names which to be fair sounds quite awful idea